# Regex matches repeated group in parent group

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I tried to match multiple group which under another group.

**Input**

```
182507 { 6661(T) }, 182514 { 5551(T), 5553(T), 5552(T) }
```

**Output**

```
Full match: 182507 { 6661(T) }
Group 1: 182507
Group 2: 6661(T)

Full match: 182514 { 5551(T), 5553(T), 5552(T) }
Group 1: 182514
Group 2: 5551(T)
Group 3: 5553(T)
Group 4: 5552(T)
```

*I tried the pattern but not seems to work that I excepted*

```
/([0-9]+)\s*\{\s*(\s*[0-9]+\s*\(\s*[A-Z]+\s*\))\s*?(?:,*\s*([0-9]+\s*\(\s*[A-Z]+\s*\))\s*)*+\s*\}+/
```

Comment: "not seems to work that I excepted": What exactly does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that repeated capturing groups only capture the last match of that group, hence your regex does not capture `5553(T)` in the second part of the string. It is probably simpler to do this using a two-step approach, first to match the digits followed by the part in `{}`, and then split that second part into its components:

```
$string = '182507 { 6661(T) }, 182514 { 5551(T), 5553(T), 5552(T) }';
preg_match_all('/(\d+)\s*{\s*([^}]+)\s*}/', $string, $matches);
$output = array();
foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $value) {
    $output[$key] = array_merge(array($value), preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $matches[2][$key]));
}
print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 182507
            [1] => 6661(T) 
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 182514
            [1] => 5551(T)
            [2] => 5553(T)
            [3] => 5552(T) 
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Mdd2T)